# Finding the N th Occurrence of a Match line

Tags: regex

I have list (multiline text string) with same number of line (order of items may differ in many ways and numbers of line may be however):

```
Ardei
Mere
Pere
Ardei
Castraveti
```

I want to find **2 th** occurrence of a match line that contain '**Ardei**' and replace name of item with another name and, separately in another regex, find **1 st** occurrence of '**Ardei**' and replace name with something else (perl).

Comment: Why do you want to do it with regex?  Who is putting that requirement on you?

Comment: What language are you using? JavaScript, C#, PHP, etc... all have different regular expression features/limitations.

Comment: I have formatted the text - is this correct now? Is that "list" a multiline text string? Can there be more than just three lines in that "list"? Can there be more than one match? You need to specify the rules more exactly - please edit your question and provide some details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you want to replace the 2<sup>nd</sup> `"Ardei"` with `"XYZ"`. You could do that like this (PCRE syntax):

```
^(?s)(.*?Ardei.*?)Ardei
```

and replace it with:

```
$1XYZ
```

The `$1` contains everything that is captured in `(.*?Ardei.*?)` and the `(?s)` will cause the `.` to match really every character (also line break chars).

A little demo:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

my $text = 'Ardei
Mere
Pere
Ardei
Castraveti
Ardei';

$text =~ s/^(?s)(.*?Ardei.*?)Ardei/$1XYZ/; 
# or just: $text =~ s/^(.*?Ardei.*?)Ardei/$1XYZ/s; 

print $text;
```

will print:

```
Ardei
Mere
Pere
XYZ
Castraveti
Ardei
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Ardei[\W\w]*?(Ardei)
```

will match exactly the second "Ardei" by its \1, so you can use it to replace exactly the second instance.

Comment: No, that will find the last `"Ardei"` in a string containing at least 2 `"Ardei"`'s.

Comment: Yes, I forgot about the greediness of regexps, corrected my solution now!