# Finding the n'th occurrence of a match in line with perl

Tags: regex, perl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Finding the N th Occurrence of a Match line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7352299/finding-the-n-th-occurrence-of-a-match-line)

I have multi-line text with:

- ship
- plane
- ship
- car

I want to find the 1st occurrence of "ship" in a line and output:

> The ship is a 1'st one.

I want find 2nd occurrence of "ship" in a line and output:

> The ship is a 2'nd one.

Comment: What don't you know how to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Lingua::EN::Inflect 'ORD';

my $text = "ship plane\n ship\n car";
my @ships = $text =~ /(ship)/g;
for ( my $i = 0; $i < @ships; $i++ ) {
    my $ship_num = ORD($i + 1);
    print "The ship is the $ship_num one\n";
}
```

`&ORD` will take care of your ordinal suffixes.

Answer (score 0):

```
$n = 1;
while (<>)
{
    if (m%ship%)
    {
       print "The ship is the $n th one\n"; # You can do the st, nd etc
       ++$n;
    }
}
```

Should work

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -lne'
   if (/^ship$/) {
      ++$seen;
      print "The is a 1'\''st one" if $seen == 1;
      print "The is a 2'\''nd one" if $seen == 2;
   }
' file
```

Or if you want more than the first two:

```
perl -lne'
   print "The is a ", ++$seen, " one" if /^ship$/;
' file
```

There's probably a module to handle finding the right suffix. I'll let you look into that.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
my $th 
    =  (  ( int( $n % 100 / 10 ) != 1 )
       && [ qw<th st nd rd> ]->[ $n % 10 ]
       )
    || 'th'
    ;
print "The ship is the $n$th one."
```